# WP7 Bing search app connect

Tags: windows-phone-7

Mango has a feature called [app connect(at 0:40)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBISUhRIiSE). which makes the user the open the application with data related to bing search query. and the application is opened directly to a specific page which is relate to the search data.

How to enable app connect feature to integrate application to bing search. How does it work..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSDN has an article explaing how to do this:

[How to: Extend Search with App Connect for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286420%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

You may also be interested in the [Search Extensibility Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202957%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: To test this feature.. whether our app should be in marketplace.?

Comment: @Mahantesh the second link includes details of how to test this